# How to discover SNMP devices

Tags: monitoring, snmp, discovery

I'm looking to set up a monitoring system and was reading quite a bit about SNMP. I don't yet have practical experience with it.

I didn't quite understand how an NMS discovers SNMP capable devices.
To put it simply, what I gather is that it's a two step process:

1. Get some IP addresses/subnets
2. Send SNMP requests to these addresses (assuming knowledge of the correct community string) and wait for replys

My questions in this context:

1. Is this how it works? If not, then how it does?
2. Is possible to set an SNMP agent to send a trap to a multicast address?

Thanks

Comment: You might get some ideas from https://docs.sharpsnmp.com/en/latest/tutorials/device-discovery.html But of course, NMS might have its algorithms.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check about the rfc you refer to in your post. I understand that there isn't an agreed upon methodology for SNMP device discovery, so each NMS has its own methods, as you said.